# How to import state created on another server?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kops

I setup my Kubernetes cluster using kops, and I did so from local machine.  So my `.kube` directory is stored on my local machine, but I setup `kops` for state storage in `s3`.

I'm in the process of setting up my CI server now, and I want to run my `kubectl` commands from that box. How do I go about importing the existing state to that server?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To run `kubectl` command, you will need the cluster's apiServer URL and related credentials for authentication. Those data are by convention stored in `~/.kube/config` file. You may also view it via `kubectl config view` command.

In order to run `kubectl` on your CI server, you need to make sure the `~/.kube/config` file contains all the information that `kubectl` client needs.

With kops, a simple naive solution is to:

1) install kops, kubectl on your CI server

2) config the AWS access credential on your CI server (either via IAM Role or simply env vars), make sure it has access to your s3 state store path

3) set env var for kops to access your cluster:

```
  export NAME=${YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME}
  export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://${YOUR_CLUSTER_KOPS_STATE_STORE}
```

4) Use kops export command to get the kubecfg needed for running kubectl

```
  kops export kubecfg ${YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME}
```

see https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cli/kops_export.md

Now the `~/.kube/config` file on your CI server should contain all the information `kubectl` needs to access your cluster.

Note that this will use the default admin account on your CI server. To implement a more secure CI/CD environment, you should create a service account bind to a required permission scope (a namespace or type or resources for example), and place its credential on your CI server machine.

Comment: when I do this, I get `cannot find CA certificate`. I tried looking in the state store but I don't see it there. Any advice on whether I missed a step, or if something else is set up incorrectly? `~/.kube/config` does not seem to know about my cluster, but kops does.

Comment: @szeitlin did you run the kops export step? if it exports successfully then you should expect the `~/.kube/config` file to contain information of your cluster

Comment: Yes, I tried to run it, and I get that error saying that it can't find the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

`.kube/config` is hardly a "state", it's just a client configuration, so it is possible to just take the content of it (or its part if you have more contexts localy) and use on another machine. That is unless you want to create a dedicated user (key/cert) for CI, in which case you need to create a separate credentials and if you use key/cert they'd need to be for a different certificate "subject" so the users can be recognised as different ones