# Connect local instance of kubectl to GKE cluster without using gcloud tool?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

Does anyone know how to connect a local instance of `kubectl` to a Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster, without using the `gcloud` tool locally?

**For example:**

If you use the `gcloud` tool with this command:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials NAME [--zone=ZONE, -z ZONE] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]
```

You'll find a user like this in `~/.kube/config`:

```
- name: gke_myproj_myzone
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: TOKENSTRING
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: /google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
        expiry: 2018-01-22 18:05:46
        expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
        token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
      name: gcp
```

As you can see, the default values, the `gcloud` tool provides require the `glcoud` tool as an *auth-provider* to log in to your cluster.

Now, what I'm looking for is a way to connect `kubectl` to a cluster on a machine, that does not have `gcloud` installed.

Comment: It seems that your question is very similar to this [one](https://serverfault.com/questions/893243/how-to-connect-to-a-vpc-on-google-cloud-using-vpn). If it is not the same, provide information on your use case.

Comment: what about `google cloud shell`?

Comment: @Fady, couldn't find the solution there.

Comment: @AmiHollander How should I use GCS to connect my laptop to the remote cluster?

Comment: @Rotareti The gcloud command above will pass all necessary auth info to ~/.kube/config, if you copy that file to your laptop ($HOME/.kube), you should be able use kubectl commands as if authenticated. Check this similar  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306904/configure-kubectl-command-to-access-remote-kubernetes-cluster-on-azure#45279302)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is by copying the `~/.kube/config` file (from a gcloud authenticated instance) to this directory `$HOME/.kube` in your local instance (laptop).

But first, and using the authenticated instance, you would have to enable legacy cluster per this [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/iam-integration#using_legacy_cluster_certificate_or_user_credentials) by running these commands:

```
gcloud config set container/use_client_certificate True
export CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_USE_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE=True
```

Then execute the `get-credentials` command, and copy the file.

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials NAME [--zone=ZONE, -z ZONE] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]
```

Note that you may have to run the `get-credentials` command, and copy the config file every time authentication tokens (saved in the config file) expire.

Comment: Is there no other way? I don't want to copy the authentication tokens again and again.

Comment: Not really sure if it is possible. The only alternative I know is to use gcloud locally on your machine and it should automatically generate the tokens. But you need to install and initiate the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/).

Answer (score 3):

You may use `kubectl` with either a user account, or a service account.

User accounts are designed to be used by humans, hence the apparent "limitation" of the tools: if you use a GKE cluster, a user is assumed to have `gcloud` installed and being logged in with it.

You may instead use a service account, which is designed to be used by software. Kubernetes has a dedicated resource type [ServiceAccount](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/) (not to confuse it with GCP service accounts!). Added benefit - it is a k8s feature, so it doesn't depend on the service implementation you use (GKE, AKS, etc.).

**Approach:**

You only need `gcloud` tool to connect to the cluster for the very first time. Once you have access to the cluster, you can create a new k8s [ServiceAccount](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/) and use its token in the `kubectl` config file.

The service account however will need to be [assigned necessary roles](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) (k8s `Role` and `RoleBinding` resources) in a fine-grained manner.

Your cluster needs to have RBAC authentication enabled for this to work.

**Word of caution:**

Service account tokens do not expire and therefore special care should be taken to never expose/compromise them. It is probably a good idea to rotate them.

**Simple(istic) example:**

This a simplified example of how the above can be done. It is rather simplistic because it uses a default namespace, only adds a few roles, and requires a fair amount of manual actions, but it can help you to get started with your own implementation.

Create a file `my-service-account.yaml`:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: my-user
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: my-user-role
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods"]
    verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: my-user-role-binding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: my-user
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: my-user-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

and run `kubectl apply -f my-service-account.yaml` to create the resources.

Once the service account is created you can run `kubectl get secrets` to find the secret that holds the user token (it has it's name derived from the service account name), then run `kubectl get secret <secret-name-here> -o yaml` to get the secret data, and find a token in the `data.token` field in the output. The token is base64-encoded, so you will need to decode it first before using in the `kubectl` config file (you can use `base64 -d` in Linux for this). In the end, relevant part of the `kubectl` config file may look like:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
  ...
contexts:
  ...
users:
- name: my-user
  user:
    token: <token-value-here>
```

Now you may switch `kubectl` context to the one you created for this user, and run:

```
kubectl get pods
```

The newly created user can only do the above and pretty much nothing else, since this is what is configured in the associated role. You can find out more about RBAC and the role configuration in the Kubernetes documentation: [Using RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/).

Comment: Amazing, thank you! It was hard to get generated credentials, but I have followed this and it worked out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47776588/731938

Comment: Thank you, this approach worked very well for me! I consider this to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

So I have created this tool called [gke-kubeconfig](https://github.com/mie00/gke-kubeconfig) to do so. I basically reverse engineered gcloud and did the same. It requests a short term token first and then use it to get the cluster data and create kube config.

You need to make sure that the token does not expire while you are using the config file, it currently expires after 1 hour so usually it shouldn't be a problem.

I have also created [mie00/gke-kubeconfig](https://hub.docker.com/r/mie00/gke-kubeconfig) to use in my CI pipeline.