# How to acces Google kubernetes cluster without googlecloud SDK?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm having trouble figuring out how I can set my kubectl context to connect to a googlecloud cluster without using the gcloud sdk. (to run in a controlled CI environment)

I created a service account in googlecloud
Generated a secret from that (json format)

From there, how do I configure kubectl context to be able to interact with the cluster ?

Comment: why don't you show us what you have done till now and where exactly you are stuck

Comment: I'm exactly at the point I described :)
I just have a json generated by googlecloud interface, and need to know how to configure kubectl context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect local instance of kubectl to GKE cluster without using gcloud tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394610/connect-local-instance-of-kubectl-to-gke-cluster-without-using-gcloud-tool)

Comment: Indeed, although the accepted answer feels for like a workaround rather than a clean solution.
Will be using the official google cloud sdk docker image in the meantime so I can directly consume that json file

Answer (score 0):

Right in the Cloud Console you can find the connect link

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials "your-cluster-name" --zone "desired-zone" --project "your_project"
```

But before this you should configure gcloud tool.