# Can I access multiple clusters from single k8s dashbaord?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cluster

I have two servers with k3s setup. I have install [k8s-dashboard](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/) on server1.

I have setup [clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306904/configure-kubectl-command-to-access-remote-kubernetes-cluster-on-azure) in server1 i.e. I can access k8s resources of server2 from server1.

```
kubectl config set-cluster server2 --server=https://{IP_OF_SERVER2}:6443
kubectl config set-context server2 --cluster=server2
kubectl config use-context server2
```

But I want to access all resources of server2 from k8s dashboard of server1.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

First, The Kubernetes dashboard needs to query [dashboard-metrics-scraper](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/dashboard-metrics-scraper), so you will need to install that before linking the dashboard UI with `scraper`.

Second from the code, it does not look like it accept array, but accept string.

```
# Metrics Scraper sidecar host for dashboard
K8S_DASHBOARD_SIDECAR_HOST=${K8S_DASHBOARD_SIDECAR_HOST:-"http://localhost:8000"}
```

[Scraper sidecar](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/1148f7ba9f9eadd719e53fa3bc8bde5b7cfdb395/aio/develop/run-npm-on-container.sh#L62)

[docker-env](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/1148f7ba9f9eadd719e53fa3bc8bde5b7cfdb395/aio/develop/run-npm-on-container.sh#L98)

So you will need deploy Metrics Scraper sidecar on the cluster 2 and then you will need to expose the service and might need two instance of the dashboard.

so better to create dashboards on its own cluster.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a single dashboard for all clusters, try [Lens IDE](https://k8slens.dev/)